# How to fix div aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I need to keep `div` aspect ration as 4:3 in both case when browser mostly horizontal or vertical. And need div size to increase as browser window increase.

I found this solution to set `padding-bottom: 75%; width: 100%;`. It works when browser window is dominantly vertical, but **when browser window is dominantly horizontal, I don't get the result as desired**.

Do you have any idea? Would you recommend using `Javascript`? If so, then how?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ex1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind explaining more what you mean by "but [it works] not when browser window is dominantly horizontal." So your goal is to have 100% of the div visible?

Comment: if you need this for a video element say yes and I'll tell you how to get rid of the div completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using padding hack to get element ratio does not work with borders -- border makes it square. Below are 2 cases, one without max width container, and one with it.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.r-4by3-wrap {
  max-width: calc(100vmin * 4 / 3);
  margin: auto;
}

.r-4by3 {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="r-4by3-wrap">
  <div style="border: 10px solid red">
    <div class="r-4by3" style="background: pink">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @János , Added no-container cace. I would not rely on viewport units because often fixed aspect elements need to work within other elements.

Comment: @János , Ah, I think I finally understand the question. Did you want it to remain fixed ratio within the viewport?

Comment: Alas, no. The whole padding hack depends on height being 0. If you want something more flexible, you will need to do some math with `calc`. See https://medium.com/buildit/hardcore-css-calc-bdfb0162993c for inspiration. Your math will be much simpler. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203937/discussion-between-kornieff-and-janos).

Comment: Hi! Why 2nd div `<div style="border: 10px solid red">` need?

Comment: Just there for the demo, no functional purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the fact that you need to consider the screen as a reference then you can do this by adding a `max-width` using `vh` unit to avoid having the element bigger than the sreen height. The ratio is `4:3` so when the element is `100vh` the width need to be `133.33vh` so the element should never exceed this width.

You need to also apply the padding trick to a child element since the parent will not have full with in all the cases and the padding is related to the upper container. Applying it to the div will give wrong result.

```css
div.ex1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* Don't forget this to include the border in the height/width*/
  width: 100%;
  max-width:133vh; /* 4/3 * 100vh */
  margin:auto;
}
div.ex1:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:75%;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! I appended your solution and how it is rendered to the question. I can see only one red line on the top. Strange.

Comment: @János you forgot a big part of my CSS code .. check again please

Answer (score 0):

You can also use media queries to check the aspect ratio and change the height and width for the div accordingly.

Just to clarify:

> **vmin** - Equal to the smaller of vw and vh.

Quoted from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

---

With that in mind we can do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body { padding:0; margin:0; text-align: center;}
    div.ex1 {
      border: 1px solid red;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
      div.ex1 {
        width: 133.33vmin;
        height: 100vmin;
      }
    }

    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
      div.ex1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 75vw;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ex1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the percent of height doesn't work, try to use [vh](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vh) instead of percent.

Comment: Instead of 75% use 75vh that is 75% of the viewport height :)

Comment: change to `75vh` does not keep the aspect ratio

Comment: Try to give your `div` `100vh` height

Comment: if you want fully responsive 4:3 aspect ratio use javascript, it's easy to do that

Comment: Look at my another answer and try it yourself, I'll help you if you need but try :D

Answer (score -3):

Use javascript `window.onresize` event

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // Here get the height of page and give them multiplied bu 4/3 to the width of div
};
```

Comment: Was thinking the same thing but OP didn't add javascript tag.

Comment: What is "OP" ? I don't understand sorry :c

Comment: Original poster - the person who asked the question.

Comment: Oh sorry lol, I think he didn't know that it was possible, or he just gave a basic example without thinking

Comment: I think he definitely new it was possible but wanted a clean solution without adding a maybe unnecessary dependency to javascript.

Comment: The poster is also asking how. The question doesn't give me the impression they would know how to retrieve the limiting dimensions and calculate the target size.